# The Sum of molecular weight of proteins in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to calculate the sum of the molecular weight of a protein sequence. I think the beginning is right, but i don't understand how i can make the sum of this sequence.

```
import string
seq = 'DHPFWKQTACKHV'
weights = {'A': 71.04, 'C': 103.01, 'D': 115.03, 'E': 129.04, 'F': 147.07,
       'G': 57.02, 'H': 137.06, 'I': 113.08, 'K': 128.09, 'L': 113.08,
       'M': 131.04, 'N': 114.04, 'P': 97.05, 'Q': 128.06, 'R': 156.10,
       'S': 87.03, 'T': 101.05, 'V': 99.07, 'W': 186.08, 'Y': 163.06 }
weight = sum()
print ("The molecular weight of this protein is", weight)
```

Comment: Start by obtaining a list of weights

Comment: sum(weights.values())

Answer (score 7):

For each protein `p` in `seq`, add its weight, which is `weights[p]` to `weight` :

```
weight = sum(weights[p] for p in seq) # => 1577.7599999999998
```

Comment: what is wrong with using just sum(weights.values())

Comment: Because `sum(weights.values())` sums the weights of all the proteins, those in the `seq`, and those not in the `seq`, but he only wants those in the `seq`.

Comment: Thanks for explanation

Comment: glad to help :).

Answer (score 0):

```
weight = sum(weight_table[x] for x in seq) - (len(seq) - 1) * water
```

see [https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/c560c95b6575686b4e84637111d4a4bf070053ae/Bio/SeqUtils/**init**.py#L485](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/c560c95b6575686b4e84637111d4a4bf070053ae/Bio/SeqUtils/__init__.py#L485)

Amino acids bind to each other to make polypeptide chains via a condensation reaction, which involves the elimination of a water molecule for each bond formed.